# Не приходит отклик от нажатия кнопки в боте telegram на Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, azure

Проблема в том что при нажатии кнопки в telegram - в контроллер бота не приходит никаких активностей. Или я их не правильно ловлю.
+ после нажатия бот выводит сообщение "sorry, my bot code is having an issue".

Стандартный класс контроллер для получения активностей на Microsoft Bot Framework.

```
 [BotAuthentication]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity != null && activity.GetActivityType() == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new finder_worker());
        }
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }
        return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
    }

    private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
    {
        if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
        {
            // Implement user deletion here
            // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
            // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
            // Not available in all channels
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle add/remove from contact lists
            // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
        {
            // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
        {
            //message.p
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Это класс который я написал как воркер по активностям. Он использует `HeroCard` для создания кнопок.

```
[Serializable]
public class finder_worker : IDialog<object>
{
    private const string mark = "sad";
    private const string st_message = "start";
    private const string empty_message = "";

    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        //тут их отлавливает
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

    }

    public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
    {
        try
        {
            var message = await argument;
            var message_to_send = context.MakeMessage();
            workers.json_worker m = new workers.json_worker(message.ChannelData.ToString());
            await context.PostAsync($"сообщение: {m.message_text}");

            switch (m.message_text)
            {
                case st_message:
                    await context.PostAsync($"инициация знакомства");
                    break;
                case empty_message:
                    await context.PostAsync($"пустое сообщение");
                    break;
                case mark:
                    message_to_send.Attachments.Add(create_button());
                    await context.PostAsync(message_to_send);
                    await context.PostAsync($"тестовое сообщение");
                    //create_button();
                    break;
                default:
                    await context.PostAsync($"прочее сообщение");
                    break;
            }
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
        catch(SqlException e)
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"упс... что то не получилось записать на сервер{e.ToString()}");
        }
    }

    public Attachment create_button()
    {

        var card = new HeroCard("Some Text");
        card.Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
        {
            new CardAction()
            {
                Title = "button1",
                Type=ActionTypes.MessageBack,
                Value="button1"
            },
            new CardAction()
            {
                Title = "button2",
                Type=ActionTypes.MessageBack,
                Value="button2"
            }
        };

        Attachment cardAttachment = card.ToAttachment();
        return cardAttachment;
    }
}
```

В качестве теста отправляю боту `sad` и жду инициации кнопок. Эта часть проходит хорошо. Но после нажатия бот не получает каких либо сообщений или других активностей. Я ожидаю получить сообщение или иной activity который можно обработать инструментами Microsoft Bot Framework.

Пробовал:

- указать тип `CardAction` как: `MessageBack`, `PostBack`, `ImBack`
- отправлять кнопки через `activity.CreateReply`

Спасибо!

Comment: брекпоинт внутри MessageReceivedAsync ставили?

Comment: кнопки обычные или инлайн?

Comment: брекпоинт не ставил, по моему нет смысла так как локально код не выполняется. только в azure. кнопки инлайн

Comment: какая разница где выполняется код, пишете ведь его вы, значит и отлаживаете тоже. эмулятор сервисов ажура установите себе и пропишите коннекты на него, сможете отлаживать